# Error "Element type is invalid" reactjs project

Tags: reactjs

everything was working just fine and all of a sudden I get this mind boggling error, went back a commit to when things were working and I'm still getting this error, i've not a clue why

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of `p`.

```js
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of `p`.
▶ 25 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
C:/Users/Jseto/Desktop/jsetome/src/index.js:27
  24 | 
  25 | const app = document.getElementById('root');
  26 | 
> 27 | ReactDOM.render(
  28 |  <HashRouter>
  29 |   <Switch>
  30 |    <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
```

Comment: This all occured after attempting to use this npm module

"react-animation-components"

Comment: Can you uninstall the module and then run again? Remove the parts of the code where this module is used. What happens in that case?